# Can you set the initial pitch and zoom of react-native-maps

Tags: google-maps, react-native, mapkit, apple-maps, react-native-maps

I'd like to start the map in the extruded building view in react native - so that we can see the 3d building models.  I think this would require me to set the pitch and zoom level.

I see the options for zoom level but I don't see any way to programmatically set the pitch.  Is this possible?  Is this possible cross-platform?

Comment: I think zoom level is set through the delta values. You can read more about delta values and how to use them from [this article](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/mkmapview-and-zoom-levels-a-visual-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the pitch / viewing angle with `animateToViewingAngle(angle, duration)` [[Documentation](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods)]

Here you can find some GIFs to take a look at the effect: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/pull/1544#issuecomment-325169134

Comment: seems like I can't set the region and the viewing angle at the same time, and running the animations in sequence doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oh, you're right, there is currently an open issue on GitHub with that problem: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/1726